# dockerfile, output evaluated commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, podman, buildah

Is there anyway to have docker create output the evaluated line?

for example

```
# Dockerfile
COPY ${SRC}/file .
```

will echo `Step 1/1 COPY ${SRC}/file .`

I want it to output instead `Step 1/1 COPY src/file .`

Edit: I'm open to other packers that are somewhat compatible with Docker files, such as `buildah bud`

Answer (score 1):

Open an issue with Buildah, and I think this would be a reasonable change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try listing the contents of the directory by using `ls` in the next step.

Comment: that only solves the example. it might be something like `RUN java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar app.jar` for example.